# Powershell Script Teams get-team -displayname with blank space in variable

Tags: powershell, microsoft-teams

I have a CVS list that contains 3 columns, one of has the header Fullname.

I want to create teams with display name fullname

Then I want to copy the group ID from that new team to a variable to add a User as a owner.

```
foreach($team in $list)
{
    New-Team -displayname $team.Fullname -Template "EDU_class"

    $GroupID = get-team -DisplayName $team.Fullname | Select-Object GroupID

}
```

When I run my code, $GroupID is empty. Fullname has some space like : ABC-School Name-Classe Number-Year

I presume that's the problem ... If I run :

```
get-team -DisplayName "ABC-School Name-Classe Number-Year" | Select-Object GroupID
```

It Works, so How to deal with ?

Comment: If you only run `Get-Team` after it's been created is there any output? It takes some time for the Teams API to create a new Team as it has to create the Team, SP site, etc. I had an instance in the past where I had to script a do/until loop with a 1sec sleep that ran until `Get-Team` yielded a result. This insured the rest of my commands ran successfully.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($team in $list)
{
    $team = New-Team -displayname $team.Fullname -Template "EDU_class"

    if ($team) { $GroupID = $team.GroupId }
}
```